# Change Listbox options on another field selection in Silverstripe

Tags: php, silverstripe

Is there any way to make `ListBoxField` automatically change it's values by selecting another `ListBoxField`? The second `ListBox` should be dependent on the first `ListBox` selection.

In my Silverstripe 3 back end I have two `ListBoxField`s. When the *Category* `Listbox` is changed the *Locations* `Listbox` should change the available options to select.

```
$fields = new FieldList(
    TextField::create('Title', 'Title'),
    UploadField::create('File', 'File')->setFolderName('Uploads/Files')->setAllowedExtensions(array('odt', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'doc', 'docx', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'ppt', 'pdf')),
    ListboxField::create('Categories', 'Categories')->setMultiple(true)->setSource(Category::get()->map('ID', 'Title'))->setAttribute('data-placeholder', 'Click to select'),
    ListboxField::create('Locations', 'Locations')->setMultiple(true)->setSource(Location::get()->map('ID', 'Title'))->setAttribute('data-placeholder', 'Click to select')
);
return $fields;
```

Comment: there is a plugin for dependent dropdowns: https://github.com/sheadawson/silverstripe-dependentdropdownfield but this works with DropdownFields, not ListboxFields as in your code (so no 'setMultiple' option here)

Answer (score 0):

Not by default.

You could try this module: https://github.com/unclecheese/silverstripe-display-logic

Comment: could be handy if the dropdowns are quite statically and you can generate a bunch of 2nd labels in seperate fields. but you cannot switch the options of a labelfield with it.

Answer (score 0):

I am echoing @schellmax comment to use...

- github.com/sheadawson/silverstripe-dependentdropdownfield

This allows one drop down to automatically update on change of another dorp down.  You make a simple function that is called with the selected value, that returns the values for the dependant drop down.

```
// 1. Create a callable function that returns an array of options for the DependentDropdownField. 
// When the value of the field it depends on changes, this function is called passing the 
// updated value as the first parameter ($val)
$datesSource = function($val) { 
    if ($val == 'one') {
        // return appropriate options array if the value is one.
    }
    if ($val == 'two') {
        // return appropriate options array if the value is two.
    }
}; 

$fields = FieldList::create(
    // 2. Add your first field to your field list, 
    $fieldOne = DropdownField::create('FieldOne', 'Field One', array('one' => 'One', 'two' => 'Two')),
    // 3. Add your DependentDropdownField, setting the source as the callable function 
    // you created and setting the field it depends on to the appropriate field
    DependentDropdownField::create('FieldTwo', 'Field Two', $datesSource)->setDepends($fieldOne)
);
```